# An interview question in java

Tags: java

```
String a = new String ("TEST");
String b = new String ("TEST");

if(a == b) { 
  System.out.println ("TRUE"); 
} else {
 System.out.println ("FALSE"); 
}
```

I tried it and it printed `FALSE`, I want to know the reason exactly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you think it is? ( hint: grab a text editor and a compiler and find out )

Comment: @@OscarRyz: I want to know the reason exactly. That's why i posted here

Comment: Then ask: *"I'm getting this but I thought I would get that.. why is it etc. etc"*

Comment: You could have tried it and posted the output and asked why it was the output.

Comment: Actually, I'll say it won't compile....what's `s.o.p`? *sarcastic laugh*

Comment: @scheffield.. I take it you don't understand the word "sarcastic" :P

Comment: lol... yeah reading till the end...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It prints `FALSE`.

The `==` operator compares object references, `a` and `b` are references to two different objects, hence the `FALSE`.

Guido said:
 
Additionally, the references are different because the Strings are created using the new operator. If you create them as `String a = "TEST"; String b = "TEST";` then the output will probably be `TRUE` because the JVM checks the existence of a matching String object in the String pool it keeps, so the same object would be reused.

Comment: Additionally, the references are different because the Strings are created using the new operator.  If you create them as String a = "TEST"; String b = "TEST"; then the output will probably be TRUE because the JVM checks the existence of a matching String object in the String pool it keeps, so the same object would be reused.

Comment: It _WILL_ be true, not "probably".

Comment: @Thorbjørn 100% sure?  Does the Java/JVM specification says that the String pool is mandatory and anything about its size or how long String references have to be kept?  I don't know why but my intuition claims that it is only 99.9999% sure.

Comment: @Guido, from http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html section 3.10.5 " String literals-or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28)-are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern.".   In your example the two "TEST" are string literals.

Answer (score 1):

The code would print FALSE. A corrected version of the code would use .equals() instead of ==

```
String a = new String ("TEST");

String b = new String ("TEST");

if(a.equals(b)) { 
  s.o.p ("TRUE"); 
} else {
 s.o.p ("FALSE"); 
}
```

Comment: Fair enough but as Alberto had already explained this I was just adding how to correct it. Next time I'll reference the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it complete:

```
String a = new String ("TEST").intern();

String b = new String ("TEST").intern();

System.out.println(a == b);
```

This will return `true` in most cases.

Thats the reason for this:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    // will return true
    System.out.println(compare("TEST", "TEST"));
}

public static boolean compare (String a, String b) {
    return a == b;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this works only for string literals, since they reuse object. In general case `equals` should be preferred over `==`.

Comment: works for any intern()ed string, literal or otherwise.  However, it a BAD idea to depend on this behaviour. equals() is the best to use.

Comment: Your both right. I just wanna show that there is a possibility to use Object equalety. The same holds true for `Interger.valueOf(200) == Integer.valueOf(200);`...

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new object ( either string or any other )  what gets returned is a copy of the value reference to that new object.

When two objects have the same reference, the `==` operator will evaluate to true.

ie.

```
Object o = new Object();
Object p = o; //<-- assigning the same reference value
System.out.println("o == p ? " + (o == p ) ); //<-- true
```

When you create two objects each one have their own reference value:

```
Object a = new Object();
Object b = new Object();
System.out.println("o == p ? " + (o == p ) ); //<-- false
```

Same thing happens with Strings objects.

When you assign a string literal, you get the same reference:

```
String x = "hello";
String y = "hello";

System.out.println("x == y ? " + (x == y ) ); //<-- true
```

But you example you're **creating** new objects, hence they have different reference values.

The effectively compare strings ( or any other Object ) , you should use the `equals()` method.

String literals are by default sent to an *string pool* to enhance performance.

If you want to make use of this pool, you could invoke the `intern()` method which, returns the object in the pool if it exists.

```
 String a = "world";
 String b = new String("world");
 String c = new String("world").intern();//<-- returns the reference value in the pool.


 System.out.println("a == b ? "  + (a==b) ); //<-- false
 System.out.println("b == c ? "  + (b==c) ); //<-- false
 System.out.println("a == c ? "  + (a==c) ); // true!
```

Answer (score 0):

If two String variables point to the same object then these two variables are called references for the same object,

So if u want to  check this comparison programmatically,  == **operator** is used. If **two variables** refers the **same object** then this operator returns **true** value and if they don't then **false** value is returned

Answer (score -1):

Here we are using two new keywords. For every new keyword a new object is generated.

The `==` method checks for the `hashcode` of the object, in this case we get `false` as the answer.